# Redirecting output of a shell script to a program

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file named `numbers.txt`. In the file I have all the numbers from 1 to 1000. And I have a program that inserts 1 to 5 in 200 round.

I tried the following script:

```
while read p; do
  echo $((p % 5 + 1))
done <numbers.txt
```

It prints numbers from 1 to 5 in 200, as expected.

Now I need to redirect the output to the input of my program. I tried this:

```
./my-program < while read p; do
  echo $((p % 5 + 1))
done <numbers.txt
```

But it failed an error:

> syntax error near unexpected token `do'

How can I run `./my-program` with input from the loop?

Comment: I would use a [gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try using for loop 
like

```
for i in `cat numbers.txt`; do
   echo $[ $i % 5 + 1 ]
done
```

Answer (score 1):

`./my-program < ...` - this syntax is only for files, in your case you want to use this type of redirection:

```
while read p; do
  echo $((p % 5 + 1))
done <numbers.txt | ./my-program
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) in Korn shell, Zsh, or Bash:

```
./my-program < <(
  while read p; do
    echo $((p % 5 + 1))
  done <numbers.txt
)
```